# bind NSTableView to both user defaults and some "current state" dictionary/array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding

What would be the recommended approach of populating a table with some rows consisting of data arrived from user defaults AND others with data arriving/changing in the run time ?

I tried to bind the table to my model's "run-time state" dictionary ("row-name": state object), but *at the same time* I'd like to bind it to the Shared User Defaults controller and this looks impossible.

Comment: it is impossible. You have to bind to an array with all data.

Comment: Yeah, looks like this. Thank you. Actually it is possible for the cell based tables with column-related bindings. But modern view-based tables do not support it.